# Компонент form.result.new меняет title страницы в режиме AJAX

Tags: ajax, битрикс

Использую компонент bitrix:form.result.new в режиме AJAX. После успешного заполнения формы изменяется title страницы. Искал в коде компонента формы, а так же в других компонентах, подключенных на странице, но везде изменение заголовков отключено. Подскажите, где и как можно это отключить?

Код вызова компонента:

```
$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    "bitrix:form.result.new",
    ".default",
    array(
        "AJAX_MODE" => "Y",
        "AJAX_OPTION_JUMP" => "N",
        "AJAX_OPTION_STYLE" => "N",
        "SET_TITLE" => "N",
        "CACHE_TIME" => "3600",
        "CACHE_TYPE" => "A",
        "CHAIN_ITEM_LINK" => "",
        "CHAIN_ITEM_TEXT" => "",
        "EDIT_URL" => "",
        "IGNORE_CUSTOM_TEMPLATE" => "N",
        "LIST_URL" => "",
        "SEF_MODE" => "N",
        "SUCCESS_URL" => "",
        "USE_EXTENDED_ERRORS" => "N",
        "WEB_FORM_ID" => "2",
        "COMPONENT_TEMPLATE" => ".default",
        "VARIABLE_ALIASES" => array(
            "WEB_FORM_ID" => "WEB_FORM_ID",
            "RESULT_ID" => "RESULT_ID",
        )
    ),
    false
);
```

Comment: В данном компоненте не происходит установка title, у него даже нет такого параметра SET_TITLE. На какой title меняется после заполнения формы?

Comment: @ka3a меняется на "Title"